# Added images in the first item, when created another item, then showing the images of previous item instead of showing empty child recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

Inside a parent linear recycler view, I’ve child grid recycler view.

When I click on the image icon, it’ll go to gallery and I can select multiple images and show in the child grid recycler view.

I’ve created an item and added images from the gallery, When I am adding another item then the images are automatically added in that item from the previous item.

How to solve it?

The complete code is provided in the below link

https://github.com/mdfaiz027/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only one list `childModelClassList` containing Uri Images. Which is read by every `parentModelClassArrayList`.

When you are adding item to `childModelClassList` this list gets updated and every `parentModelClassArrayList` is referenced to this list so the same item is shown on every grid.

The simplest way to fix it is having own `childModelClassList` for every `parentModelClassArrayList`

Something like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ParentModelClass> parentModelClassArrayList;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Uri>> childModelClassList;
    ParentAdapter parentAdapter;
    ChildAdapter childAdapter;
    FloatingActionButton btnOpenDialog;

    private static final int Read_Permission = 101;
    private static int lastClickedPosition = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.idFirstRV);

        parentModelClassArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        childModelClassList = new ArrayList<>();

        btnOpenDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenDialog);

        btnOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);

                TextView edtTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
                Button okBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
                Button cancelBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

                // ok button
                okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String title = "";

                        if(!edtTitle.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            title = edtTitle.getText().toString();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter the title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        ArrayList<Uri> uriListForParentModel = new ArrayList<>();
                        childModelClassList.add(uriListForParentModel);

                        parentModelClassArrayList.add(new ParentModelClass(title,uriListForParentModel));
                        parentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(parentModelClassArrayList.size()-1);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(parentModelClassArrayList.size()-1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                // cancel button
                cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        parentAdapter = new ParentAdapter(this, parentModelClassArrayList, this::onItemClick);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(parentAdapter);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Read_Permission);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Button " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            lastClickedPosition = position;
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            }
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(data.getClipData() != null){
                int x = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
                    childModelClassList.get(lastClickedPosition).add(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());
                }
            }
            else if(data.getData() != null){
                String imageURL = data.getData().toString();
                childModelClassList.get(lastClickedPosition).add(Uri.parse(imageURL));
            }

            parentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You know what this is why I really like stack overflow because you can find most of the solutions here, but what makes it really helpful is people like you. Who really passionate to help others. I had this problem facing for months and I regret not posting it on stack overflow. I really have to say that, you're really an experienced developer. Thanx again man. May god bless you.